# Autocomplete in package manager console exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I saw some video about Entity Framework Code First and it seems that they use some autocomplete function when type command in Package Manager Console. Does it really exist because i cannot find something like that ?
I tried `Ctrl + J` and `Ctrl + Space`(like `Intellisense` in visual studio but without success)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already found an answer )
it appears you have to hit tab in order to get command completion.